# Button overflows flex container when aspect-ratio is used

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design, aspect-ratio

Trying to place a button into flex container and make its height to be percentage of sibling's (`.task`) height. It works as expected except that button horizontally overflows parent (`.task-buttons`) and ancestor (`.task`). I have no idea why it happens.

[image]

[image]

I'd like `.task-buttons` to have the same width as its content and fit into `.task`, shrinkin `.task-todo` if needed. Exactly `.task-todo` as its parent (`.task-info`) may contain additional items that shouldn't be shrunk.

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  left: 30%;
  top: 50px;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #00000029;
}

.task {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.task-info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.task-todo {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.task-buttons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.task-inc-button {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  height: 80%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #9BE0DB;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="task">
    <div class="task-info">
      <div class="task-todo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec quis magna a sem posuere vestibulum.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="task-buttons">
        <button type="button" class="task-inc-button">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `aspect-ratio: 1;` with `width: 20px;` in `.task-inc-button` CSS, I hope it'll help you out. Thank You

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  left: 30%;
  top: 50px;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #00000029;
}

.task {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.task-info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.task-todo {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.task-buttons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.task-inc-button {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  height: 80%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #9BE0DB;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="task">
    <div class="task-info">
      <div class="task-todo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec quis magna a sem posuere vestibulum.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="task-buttons">
        <button type="button" class="task-inc-button">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for response! The problem is that it should scale if font-size of the text to the left changes.